# Work permit application for Austria

Tags: schengen, austria

My fiance has received a work contract from an Austrian company. She has a valid French "titre de sejour" (residence permit) until September 2021. I understand that she has to apply for an Austrian work permit. Can someone shed some light on how to apply for the work permit? How long does it take for the process to complete and get the Austrian RWR card?
Any tips are helpful.

Comment: Where is your fiancé residing at the moment? Have you researched the Austrian government/immigration website  in that country for the information you’re looking for?

Comment: My fiance is residing in Austria at the moment but she will go back to France in a few days. I have read about the process on the Austrian immigration website but I wanted to know some first hand experiences.